# Get a list of all shared libraries that a running service is using in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries

Some solutions I found for the above problem are : (let's take an example of a running service, say `/usr/sbin/acpid` and say the pid of the process is 1234)

1. **ldd /usr/sbin/acpid**
   Output:

   > linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe5eb7a000)
   >   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa0b1a48000)
   >   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a297a76000)
2. **sudo objdump -p /usr/sbin/acpid | grep NEEDED**
   Output:

   > NEEDED               libc.so.6
3. **sudo pmap 1234**
   Output:

   > 1234:   /usr/sbin/acpid
   >   0000000000400000     44K r-x-- acpid
   >   000000000060a000      4K r---- acpid
   >   000000000060b000      4K rw--- acpid
   >   000000000060c000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
   >   00000000020ce000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
   >   00007f0ac06c7000   1788K r-x-- libc-2.23.so
   >   00007f0ac0886000   2048K ----- libc-2.23.so
   >   00007f0ac0a86000     16K r---- libc-2.23.so
   >   00007f0ac0a8a000      8K rw--- libc-2.23.so
   >   00007f0ac0a8c000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
   >   00007f0ac0a90000    152K r-x-- ld-2.23.so
   >   00007f0ac0caa000     12K rw---   [ anon ]
   >   00007f0ac0cb3000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
   >   00007f0ac0cb5000      4K r---- ld-2.23.so
   >   00007f0ac0cb6000      4K rw--- ld-2.23.so
   >   00007f0ac0cb7000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
   >   00007ffcacbda000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
   >   00007ffcacbfb000      8K r----   [ anon ]
   >   00007ffcacbfd000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
   >   ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
   >   total             4400K
4. **readelf -d /usr/sbin/acpid | grep NEEDED**
   Output:

   > 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]

Also in the process, I learned about what exactly are shared libraries and how are they handled in Linux on a broad level.

Now here are the things that I need help with:

1. If we look at the output of each of the solutions above, *libc.so.6* is present in the output of solutions 1, 2 and 4 but not in 3. Also the output of solution 1 above reports *inux-vdso.so.1* and */lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2* as well which no other solution reports. So which of these solutions should be taken as the accurate one.
2. As per my understanding, shared libraries are loaded into the memory by the loader at runtime. Also, *on demand* a process can load any more shared libraries when ever needed. Am I right or wrong here ? In case right, the shared libraries being used by any given process could always be dynamic. So, if I really need to know the shared libraries being used by a process, will I need to poll the process all the time to figure this out ? (Am sure there is much better /elegant solution to this)
3. Solution 1, the *ldd* approach, is something I would want to avoid because of the inherent security risk it has (depending on the version of the ldd being used) of starting an executable itself to figure out it's shared libraries.

So what is the best approach to figure out the shared libraries being used by a process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> libc.so.6 is present in the output of solutions 1, 2 and 4 but not in 3.

`libc.so.6` is a symlink to `libc-2.23.so` so it is present, albeit in a different form.

> and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 as well which no other solution reports.

Ditto, it's `ld-2.23.so`.

> Also the output of solution 1 above reports inux-vdso.so.1

This is a dummy shared lib which does not exist but is emulated by kernel to increase performance of some library functions. I guess 3 has it in

```
ffffffffff600000 4K r-x-- [ anon ]
```

but it's not annotated.

> which of these solutions should be taken as the accurate one.

2 and 4 are equivalent. They are inferior to 1 and 3 because they report only *direct* dependencies of your app (not transitive dependencies of it's dependants). Further, 1 is inferior to 3 because it won't report dynamically loaded libs (via `dlopen`).

> Also, on demand a process can load any more shared libraries
>   when ever needed. Am I right or wrong here ?

Yup, that's used to implement e.g. plugins.

> So, if I really need to know the shared libraries
>   being used by a process, will I need to poll the process
>   all the time to figure this out ?
>   (Am sure there is much better /elegant solution to this)

No, there is no easier solution. You could check whether app calls `dlopen` (by scanning output of `readelf --dyn-syms -W`) - if it doesn't you are *most* *probably* fine (some really clever apps may load libs themselves via `mmap`, etc. but this is so rare that is fine to ignore).

If app *does* call `dlopen` than the best thing you can do is use solution 3. This is obviously incomplete as app may load new libs at any time, depending on it's algorithm (and there's generally no way to figure it out statically as that would be equivalent to solving the halting problem).

One approximate solution for finding *potentially* `dlopen`-ed libs would be to scan all strings in app (by running `strings` on it) and extracting everything that looks like a library name. Of course this won't catch the situations where library name is generated dynamically (e.g. read from some config file).

> Solution 1, the ldd approach, is something I would want
>   to avoid because of the inherent security risk it has
>   (depending on the version of the ldd being used) of
>   starting an executable itself to figure out it's shared libraries.

I don't think executable is started i.e. *no* app or libs code gets run.

> So what is the best approach to figure out the shared libraries being
>   used by a process?

I'd got with no. 3 (which has many equivalent variants e.g. scanning `/proc/PID/maps` or `lsof` as suggested in other post). Depending on how inclined you are about `dlopen`, you can also scan strings for potentially loaded libs but IMHO that's an overkill in majority of cases.

Comment: amazingly answered. Thanks. Could you please also point me to relevant resources that can help me understand it better ? Also, how did you figure out the symlinks part ?

Comment: "Could you please also point me to relevant resources" - well, [Drepper's dsohowto](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) is a canonical source of info. "Also, how did you figure out the symlinks part" - I knew it from prior experience :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider `lsof -p <pid>`:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof

For example:

```
lsof -p 552|grep '.so'
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153905860 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153905748 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153905744 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153905743 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153897718 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1 (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153905740 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153897705 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0 (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153905753 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153897811 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153897716 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1 (path dev=248,120)
cron    552 root  mem    REG    8,17           153905746 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so (path dev=248,120)
...
```

PS:
Yes, "2. per my understanding, shared libraries are loaded into the memory..." is correct.

Comment: In my case, lsof also gives the same results as solution 2, *pmap* approach, above, where the reported shared objects are : */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so* and */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so*. Is this information completely reliable ? Also, what about the polling of the process part.. any ideas there ?

Comment: This does not answer any of the 3 questions posed above...